# Having problem with django makemigration model.py file(message after running django : can;t import the name self)

Tags: python, django

when i run the manage.py file this is the message i ge:

(base) abu@lenovo:~/Desktop/paris_sportif$ python3 manage.py makemigrations

ImportError: cannot import name 'self' from 'typing_extensions' (/home/abu/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/typing_extensions.py)

[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcNKu.png)

Comment: `self` ≠ `Self`

Comment: `self` is a python reserved keyword, you absolutely cannot have a class named `self` in a module. Probably you want to import something else